# Как корректно считать txt файл для создания графа (Графы, поиск в глубину)

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, graph, dfs

Начала изучать графы в уни и возникают огромные проблемы с реализацией алгоритма поиска в глубину, да и вообще с созданием взвешенного графа. 
Главные 2 вопроса: как можно считать с файла .txt узел (node) и соседствующие узлы со стоимостью ребер (edge)? Пыталась сделать это в методе parseFile и застопорилась. Возможно также надо создать еще лист Узлов и туда в список добавлять их со считанного файла?
Например,
 txt file(<стартовый узел>    <соседний узел>, <стоимость>   <сосед.узел>,<стоимость>):

1   2,1 8,2

2   1,1 3,1

3   2,1 4,1

4   3,1 5,1

5   4,1 6,1

6   5,1 7,1

7   6,1 8,1

8   7,1 1,2

P.S. непонятно для чего создавать отдельно интерфейс Graph, если и без него можно создать класс Граф.

класс графа:

```
public class WeightedGraph {
    static String s = "C:\\Users\\beeem\\Desktop\\graph1.txt";

static class Graph {
        int vertices;
        LinkedList<Edge> [] adjacencylist;

        Graph(int vertices) {
            this.vertices = vertices;
            adjacencylist = new LinkedList[vertices];
            //initialize adjacency lists for all the vertices
            for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
                adjacencylist[i] = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }
/*
 * Adds the edge with reference to source and destination vertices.
 * Each source (vertex) is kept in an array and has a linkedList of edges.
 * @param source The starting vertex.
 * @param destination The adjacent vertex.
 * @param weight The cost of route between two vertices.
 */
public void addEgde(int source, int destination, int weight) {
            Edge edge = new Edge(source, destination, weight);
            adjacencylist[source].addFirst(edge); //for directed graph
        }
/*
 * Prints out the graph (the information about
 * vertex and its neighbouring adjacent vertices).
 */
public void printGraph(){
            for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
                LinkedList<Edge> list = adjacencylist[i];
                for (int j = 0; j <list.size() ; j++) {
                    System.out.println("vertex-" + i + " is connected to " +
                            list.get(j).destination + " with weight " +  list.get(j).weight);
                }
            }
        }

     public static void parseFile(String filename) throws IOException {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
                if(arr.length == 3) {
                    Node node = new Node(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
                    Node adjNode = new Node(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                    Node adjNode2 = new Node(Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
//                  Node node = new Node(arr[0]);
//                  Node adjNode = new Node(arr[1]);
//                  Node adjNode2 = new Node(arr[2]);
                    node.addNeighbors(adjNode);
                    node.addNeighbors(adjNode2);

                }
            }
    }
/*
 * Finds the cheapest way from the given node. 
 * According to Depth First Search Algorithm.
 */
 public void cheapSearch(Node node) {
     Stack <Node> stack = new Stack <Node>();
     stack.add(node);
     node.visited = true;
     while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Node element = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(element.data + " ");

        List<Node> neighbours = element.getNeighbours();
        for(int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {
            Node n = neighbours.get(i);
            if(n != null && !n.visited) {
                stack.add(n);
                n.visited = true;
            }
        }
     }
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
            int vertices = 6;
            Graph graph = new Graph(vertices);
            //for checking
            graph.addEgde(0, 1, 4);
            graph.addEgde(0, 2, 3);
            graph.addEgde(1, 3, 2);
            graph.addEgde(1, 2, 5);
            graph.addEgde(2, 3, 7);
            graph.addEgde(3, 4, 2);
            graph.addEgde(4, 0, 4);
            graph.addEgde(4, 1, 4);
            graph.addEgde(4, 5, 6);
            graph.printGraph();

        }
}
```

class Edge:

```
public class Edge {
    int source;
    int destination;
    int weight;

    public Edge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getSource() {
        return source;
    }
}
```

class Node:

```
public class Node{ 


int data;
boolean visited;
List<Node> neighbours;


public Node (int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
}

//getters and setters
public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public boolean isVisited() {
    return visited;
}

public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
    this.visited = visited;
}

public void setNeighbours(List<Node> neighbours) {
    this.neighbours = neighbours;
}


public void addNeighbors(Node neighbour) {
        this.neighbours.add(neighbour);
}

public List<Node> getNeighbours() {
        return neighbours;
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, как корректно считать данные из файла?

Comment: корректно считать, да. Если бы граф был не взвешенный, было бы проще, а в данном случае надо считать не только узлы, но и стоимости ребер.

Comment: В принципе, задание узлов вполне себе нормальное. Вообще достаточно описывать только существуещие грани, скажем строчками (1 2 8) описывает ребро между 1 и 2 узлом и 8 вес. Просто при добавлении ребра проверять есть ли этот узел уже в списке, если нет - создать новый. Так проблем не будет при добавлении новых узлов, не будет узлов без ребер

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko вообще-то в графах могут быть вершины без ребер. Поэтому формат файла должен это предусматривать. Например, вначале идут названия вершин, а потом описание ребер с их весами. Или же если в строке только один элемент, то считать его вершиной. Тут надо определиться с форматом файла, в котором описан граф.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець ну я лично не знаю задачи где могут понадобиться вершины без ребер. Они просто не участвуют в алгоритме. Но тут все зависит от того какие условия задачи

Comment: Увидела идею, что, например, можно запихать это все в хэш таблицы. Но я вроде уже создала массив из LinkedList. и вот именно с имплементацией проблема. Возможно, стоит отказаться от Edge класса, и оперировать только Node. но пока в раздумьях...

Comment: Чтото я запутался. Для начала опишите нормально формат файла. У вас там целое и 2 дробных числа? Или занятая это не разделитель дробной части? Почему вы парсите как три целых числа?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець вот пояснила получше в вопросе: сначала идет (стартовый узел  соседний узел, стоимость  соседний узел, стоимость) и так с каждой строки, т е через запятую указаны целые числа

Comment: @Майя т.е., в каждой строке описана стартовая вершина и ДВЕ соседние с ней? Тогда почему только 2? Или это пример такой? А если меньше? В общем, извините, но вы бы сформулировал вопрос по-другому. Я лично не понимаю что означают цифры в файле...

Comment: Как указано в выше в вопросе:дан числовой список, а именно <стартовый узел> <соседний узел>, <стоимость> <сосед.узел>,<стоимость> - характеристика для каждой строки